# import eclipse project into intellij gets unknown natures warnings

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I am getting warnings saying:
The event log:

```
   14:20:01 Unknown Natures Detected
             Imported projects contain unknown natures:
             /Users/name/MyWork/3.0.x/installer(org.eclipse.jem.workbench.JavaEMFNature)
             /Users/name/MyWork/3.0.x/cache(org.eclipse.jem.workbench.JavaEMFNature)

/Users/name/MyWork/3.0.x(org.eclipse.jem.workbench.JavaEMFNature)
             /Users/name/MyWork/3.0.x/jetty(org.eclipse.jem.workbench.JavaEMFNature)
             /Users/name/MyWork/3.0.x/standalone(org.eclipse.jem.workbench.JavaEMFNature)
             /Users/name/MyWork/3.0.... (show balloon)
```

I have searched but could find anything helpful. Will the warnings affect my projects ?

Comment: Can you add some screenshots of how it says !

Comment: @VinayVeluri I added the event log

Answer (score 0):

I believe JavaEMFNature suggests that your eclipse projects are using the Eclipse Modelling Framework. To the best of my knowledge, there isn't a plugin in IntelliJ which directly/fully supports EMF so you will probably find that anything in your eclipse project which is related to EMF won't work or won't be imported in intelliJ.

You may find the [Kevoree Modelling Framework](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7504?pr=) plugin for intelliJ does the same set of stuff but I'm not very familiar with it and so YMMV.